# Azure Virtual Machine, Azure AD & O365

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have Windows server 2016 VM running, so how can I give all the O365 users permissions to login in this VM using their O365 credentials only. Is there any way to do this and please provide link as well so that I will go through with the link.

In every link I am getting how to Sync on-prem AD with Azure AD. so please provide some other link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, we can't use Azure AD users to login Azure VM directly.

> How can I give all the O365 users permissions to login in this VM
>   using their O365 credentials only. Is there any way to do this and
>   please provide link as well so that I will go through with the link.

Do you mean you want to use Azure AD users to login Azure VM?

If you want to connect remotely to machines joined to the domain via Remote Desktop, you should use AAD DS(Azure AD Domain Services). More information about AAD DS, refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-overview).
[image]

> In every link I am getting how to Sync on-prem AD with Azure AD. so please provide some other link.

To Sync on-prem AD to Azure AD, we need to install Azure AD connect, more information about Azure AD connect, refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect).

Comment: Suppose we have added users in our Azure directory. I want to give access for VM to my Azure directory members. So this we can do using Azure Ad domain services? If yes could you please provide few high level steps

Comment: @Abhishekkumar Yes, there is a scenario that Azure AD Domain Services for cloud-only organizations, a cloud-only Azure AD tenant (often referred to as 'managed tenants') does not have any on-premises identity footprint.